# Java convert String UTF-8 to UTF-16

Tags: java

I try to convert String a = "try" to String UTF-16
I did this :

```
 try {
            String ulany = new String("357810087745445");
            System.out.println(ulany.getBytes().length);
            String string = new String(ulany.getBytes(), "UTF-16");
            System.out.println(string.getBytes().length);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And ulany.getBytes().length = 15
and  System.out.println(string.getBytes().length) = 24 but I think that it should be 30 what I did wrong ?

Comment: if you count repeating numbers it is 24.

Comment: Java Strings are already UTF-16. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

**String** (and **char**) hold Unicode. So nothing is needed.

However if you want **bytes**, binary data, that are in some encoding, like UTF-16, you need a conversion:

```
ulany.getBytes("UTF-16") // Those bytes are in UTF-16 big endian
ulany.getBytes("UTF-16LE")
```

However System.out uses the operating systems encoding, so one cannot just pick some different encoding.

*In fact `char` is UTF-16 encoded.*

---

What happens

```
        //String ulany = new String("357810087745445");
        String ulany = "357810087745445";
```

The String copy constructor stems from the C++ beginning, and is senseless.

```
        System.out.println(ulany.getBytes().length);
```

This will run on different platforms differently, as `getBytes()` uses
the default Charset. Better

```
        System.out.println(ulany.getBytes("UTF-8").length);

        String string = new String(ulany.getBytes(), "UTF-16");
```

This interpretes those bytes pairwise; having 15 bytes is already wrong.
Evidently one gets 7 (8?) special characters, as the high byte is not zero.

```
        System.out.println(string.getBytes().length);
```

Now getting 24 means an average 3 bytes per char. Hence the default platform encoding is probably UTF-8 creating multibyte sequences.

The string will contain something like:

```
        String string = "\u3533\u3837\u3031\u3830\u3737\u3534\u3434?";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also include a text encoding in getBytes(). For example:

```
String string = new String(ulany.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-16");
```